# Sending an email in windows phone 8 app with html content set as body to that email?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

Hi i am developing an windows phone 8 app , in which i would like to send email from my application .

sending an email can be done in this way easily in this way :-

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask(); 
emailComposeTask.To = "someone@example.com";    
emailComposeTask.Cc = "testmail@test.com"; 
emailComposeTask.Subject = "Windows Phone 8"; 
emailComposeTask.Show();
```

**But my Doubt is** :-

i have html content (which consists of a table with columns and rows constructed in html format)

1) so i wanted to set that html content as body to my email in my windows phone 8 app and send it over, how can achieve this ??

2)Are they any other ways / alternatives of accomplishing this task ??

3)Am i missing an alternative provided by Microsoft ??

Please let me know .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

convert text/string to html format, may this post can help you: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-text-to-html

Answer (score 0):

> 1) so i wanted to set that html content as body to my email in my windows phone 8 app and send it over, how can achieve this ??

By default, it's not possible. However, this post may help you: [Send HTML Content Via EmailComposeTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19031868/2549049)

> 2)Are they any other ways / alternatives of accomplishing this task ??

There could be, but as `EmailComposeTask` is for Windows phone only, so you should go with it.

> 3)Am i missing an alternative provided by Microsoft ??

Microsoft only provided this for Windows phone. [EmailComposeTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask_properties(v=vs.105).aspx)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `string.ToHtml()` which converts the whole string into a html format.