# Send HTML Content Via EmailComposeTask

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working with windows phone 8 application I need to send HTML contents using Email compose task, Any one can help me?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask.body%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you cannot use html formating using EmailComposeTask. To do that you will need to use a third party library line [MailMessage](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage) or create a web service to send the mail from the web service.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, you can't send HTML with `EmailComposeTask`. But you can do it with SendGridPlus, which I just released yesterday. Using their Web transport protocol, you can send Text & Html emails, *with attachments*. All you need is a free SendGrid account, which lets you send 200 emails/day.

Open up NuGet Package Manager (make sure you have the latest version of NuGet installed) and type `install-package SendGridPlus -pre`. Then, you can use the following code:

```
            var mail = Mail.GetInstance();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("someone@stackoverflow.com");
            mail.AddTo("you@thispost.com");
            mail.Subject = "Emails from Windows Phone!";
            mail.Html = "<b>Isn't this cool?!?</b>;
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(sg_UserName, sg_Password);
            var sendGrid = Web.GetInstance(credentials);
            sendGrid.Deliver(mail);
```

HTH!